# digraph partitioning to subgraphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, partitioning, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given a DAG with |V| = n and has s sources we have to present subgraphs such that each subgraph has approximately k1=√|s| sources and approximately k2=√|n| nodes.

If we define the height of the DAG to be the maximum path length from some source to some sink.

We require that all subgraphs generated will have approximately the same height.

The intersection of each pair of node Sets (of subgraphs)  is empty.

You can see in attached picture the example of right partition(each edge in the graph is directed upwards).

[image]

There are 36 nodes and 8 sinks [#10,11,12,13,20,21,22,23]in the example .So each subgraph should have 6 nodes and 2 or 3 sinks.

Do you have idea for algorithm?

Thank you very much

Comment: If this is homework, you should add the homework tag. Also, it would help if you provided what ideas you have for doing this.

Comment: No its not homework its part of research project.

Comment: As written, this is equivalent to finding subsets of a set. If "leaf" means a node, it just means listing all subsets of size (sqrt(|V|) taken from G (with their edges), which is trivial. If a leaf is a node with an edge that points *to* it but no edge that points *from* it, then do the same with the nodes that can be leaves (omitting edges as needed), then choose among all necessary nodes (to provide the "twigs"), then among all unnecessary nodes. This seems too easy; are you sure there aren't other conditions?

Comment: The sub graph has to be chosen in such a way that it is forbidden that the "subgraph" consists two "parts" which don`t share any common node

Comment: So you want each subgraph to be (undirectedly) connected?  Certainly not possible for all G (e.g. G has no edges).  Perhaps you mean something else, or you have a stronger condition on G?

Comment: Yes,It can be supposed that it is indirectly connected
and G is a DAG

Comment: This seems like a good problem for [CST](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com). They're out of beta now and have some really good speciallists.

Comment: You should probably learn to use Graphviz. It has a very simple syntax and produces very good looking diagrams. http://www.graphviz.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have missed some information,even if we assume the graph is indirectly connected. look at the following example.

 you should have 3 vertices in each subgraph, however, look on vertex 6, if it is without 5 - we are done, because the graph is not connected, like you said it should be in the comment.

if it is - must be with at most one of {7,8,9} - let's say it's with 7. i.e. U={5,6,7}

let's now look on 8, let's say it is in U', since 5 is not in U', there is no possible solution, in which the subset U' will be connected.

please look again at the task description and give us more details, (or give this example as a counter-example to show it might be unsolveable)

[image: contradiction]